# How to show each cell table data in popup window using datatables?

Tags: datatables

---

How to show the popup for each cell with its table data using Datatables?

In the below script script i had used datatables plugin along with alert to show popup each cell but am not getting the proper output?How can i modify the script to show each cell data in popup widow when mouse click is done inside the each cell?

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    </head>
    <table border="1" align="center" id="example" class="display"  width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
    <th>d</th>
    <th>e</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#example tbody').click( function () {
      alert("test") ;
    });
    });
    </script>
    </table>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important Note: Before adding code please include js && css to your page refer js which are use fiddle External Resources section.

Revamp your click function to on click function.

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var companyTable=  $('#jobs').DataTable();   
    $('#jobs').on('click', 'tr', function () {
      $("#company-full-name").val(companyTable.row(this).data()[1]);
      $("#company-short-name").val(companyTable.row(this).data()[2]);
      $('#DescModal').modal("show");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">On click row  popup will get open </h3>

    </div>
    <table id="jobs" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Date Posted</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--Made it easier, so no more redundant copypasta in other pages-->
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>VP Marketing</td>
                <td>Devify</td>
                <td>22.38</td>
                <td>222 Lillian Hill</td>
                <td>2015-02-17</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Administrative</td>
                <td>Skiba</td>
                <td>10.92</td>
                <td>3 Corscot Terrace</td>
                <td>2015-02-03</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Database Admini</td>
                <td>Dynazzy</td>
                <td>36.72</td>
                <td>5082 Butterfield Ter</td>
                <td>2015-01-30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Quality Control</td>
                <td>Realmix</td>
                <td>23.48</td>
                <td>598 Independence Cir</td>
                <td>2015-02-19</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Health Coach II</td>
                <td>Linkbuzz</td>
                <td>17.11</td>
                <td>18 Donald Plaza</td>
                <td>2015-02-17</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Biostatistician</td>
                <td>Roomm</td>
                <td>36.37</td>
                <td>3 Almo Terrace</td>
                <td>2015-02-16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Assistant Profe</td>
                <td>Shufflester</td>
                <td>29.43</td>
                <td>640 Towne Terrace</td>
                <td>2015-02-13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>Analog Circuit</td>
                <td>Tagcat</td>
                <td>25.66</td>
                <td>316 Claremont Road</td>
                <td>2015-02-21</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Structural Engi</td>
                <td>Tagchat</td>
                <td>35.55</td>
                <td>809 Butterfield Park</td>
                <td>2015-02-10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Senior Develope</td>
                <td>Browsecat</td>
                <td>21.62</td>
                <td>5 Sachs Court</td>
                <td>2015-01-30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Human Resources</td>
                <td>Jaxbean</td>
                <td>32.00</td>
                <td>6 Corscot Street</td>
                <td>2015-02-10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Analyst Program</td>
                <td>Jetpulse</td>
                <td>28.13</td>
                <td>30 Eggendart Place</td>
                <td>2015-02-20</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="DescModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">�</button>
                 <h3 class="modal-title">Job Requirements & Description</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="row dataTable">
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <label class="control-label">job title</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" id="company-full-name" name="companyFullName">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <br>

                                            <div class="row dataTable">
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Company</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="30" id="company-short-name" name="companyShortName">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                              <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Apply!</button>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" class="init"> body {
       font-size: 140%;
   }
   </style>
```

For DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/t53cyutt/42/

Thanks.

Comment: If i click the table data 1 .1 should be displayed in popup menu.How can i create popup menu for above code.Each table data contents should be displayed in popup when click id done.@ Dipak Thoke

Comment: @SAHO please modify your question.

Comment: can you link with jsfiddle page@Dipak Thoke

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/891mdyvy/17/  this sample code not exact asnwer you follow this code.

Comment: @SAHO Sorry for late response here  is solution your problem. Thanks You !

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html  check this solution .