# How to expand wrapped text in a shiny datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app in which the text too long and gets truncated. Is there a way to "open" (expand) this text when clicking on it? Here is my reproducible example:

```
datatable(iris[c(1:20, 51:60, 101:120), ], options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
  targets = 5,
  render = JS(
    "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
    "return type === 'display' && data.length > 6 ?",
    "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 6) + '...</span>' : data;",
    "}")
))), callback = JS('table.page(3).draw(false);'))
```

Comment: By default `title` attribute in _span_ tag will open "show" once your mouse hover over Species. If you're looking for something like modal, then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824550/how-to-show-each-cell-table-data-in-popup-window-using-datatables)

Comment: @A.Suliman Yes, by default text is shown. The problem is I need to copy the entire text, and this is not possible with the default options. Seems that modal are what I'm searching, but since I'm totally new to JS, can you help me implementing my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way based on my previous answer. Please note if you open the table in the browser *details_open.png* will work but it doesn't work in the "RStudio viewer" and will appear as a question mark.

```
library(DT)
iris$Sepal.Width <- 'Verrrrrrrrry Looooooooooooooong Commmmmmment'

iris_upd <- cbind(' ' = '<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_open.png\"/>', iris)

datatable(
    iris_upd, 
    escape = -2,
    options = list(
      columnDefs = list(
        list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0)),
        list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1),
        list(
    targets = 3,
    render = JS(
      "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
      "return type === 'display' && data.length > 6 ?",
      "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 6) + '...</span>' : data;",
      "}")
  )
      )
    ),
    callback = JS("
                  table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
                  var format = function(d) {
                  return'<p>' + d[3] + '</p>';
                  };
                  table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                  var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                  if (row.child.isShown()) {
                  row.child.hide();
                  td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_open.png\"/>');
                  } else {
                  row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                  td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_close.png\"/>');
                  }
                  });"
  ))
```

## Using column names

```
JS("
            table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
            var format = function(d, ind, tit) {
            out = '';
            for(i=0; i<ind.length; i++){
               out += tit[ind[i]] + ':' + '&ensp;' + d[ind[i]] + '<br>';
            }
            return out;
            };
            table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
            var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
            var title = table.columns().header();    //Getting all column names 'headers' 
            title_names = [];
            for (i = 0; len = title.length, i < len; i++) { 
            title_names.push(title[i].innerText);
            }
            nms = ['Species','Sepal.Width'];    //Define column names here 
            indices = [];
            for (i=0; i<nms.length; i++){
            indices.push(title_names.indexOf(nms[i]))
            }
            if (row.child.isShown()) {
            row.child.hide();
            td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_open.png\"/>');
            } else {
            row.child(format(row.data(), indices, title_names)).show();
            td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_close.png\"/>');
            }
            });"
)
```

Comment: ahah thank you very much, I was finishing to implement the code but you did it before me. By the way, worked perfectly!

Comment: I have a last question: how can I set `return'<p>' + d[3] + '</p>';` to point not on the third column but on the column name (or multiple columns)? I have a dynamic table and pointing on a row number is not convenient.

Comment: @Schottky it's an interesting question but I have no idea how to do it. I'll check and let you know ;).

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying different commands/codes but I couldn't figured it out

Comment: @Schottky please check my update, not the best solution but something works I hope.

Comment: It returns a blank page :/

Comment: It works perfectly now. By the way, I fixed the comment (that was the problem, I suppose) before your edit, but probably I didn't clear the environment :D However, thank you very much!